# How do I reattach an event to a new loaded DOM element with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling

My problem is that my click callback function only works once and it has propably something to do with the fact that after the first callback, parts of my page will be refreshed with ajax actions. But how can i reattach the event to the new loaded DOM-Elements?

this is my function:

```
// DELETE ENTRY
    $('.delete').on('click', function(){
        //// ADDING DATA-INDEX TO ENTRIES ////

        $('.id').each(function(index){
            var id = $(this).html();
            var dataIndex = $(this).attr("data-index", id);
        });

        alert('clicked');

        var action = '_includes/deleteEntry.php';
        var method = 'post';
        var entryId = $(this).siblings('.id').attr('data-index');
        var entryIdNumber = entryId.substr(entryId.length - 2);

        var data = {'id' : entryIdNumber};

        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: method,
            data: data

        }).done(function(data){
            $('.main').empty();
            $('.main').append(data);
            return;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a delegated event handler attached to a non-changing ancestor:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
```

This works by listening for an event (click) to bubble up to the ancestor, *then* it applies the jQuery selector, *then* it applies the function to any matching elements *that caused the event*. It also only connects a single handler to a single element, so is often faster to startup (if you have mutilple matches). The minuscule delay a delegated handler adds *at event time* will never be noticed as you simply cannot click that fast :)

The upshot of this is that the matching elements do not need to exist at *event registration time*, just when the event occurs so it is perfect for items that change dynamically.

`document` is the default if nothing else is closer to the changing elements. Never use `body` as the default for delegated mouse events as styling can cause it to not respond to mouse events (if it winds up with a calculated height of 0, so best to be safe).

Comment: I get the point here, but now my function won't be executed at all :(

Comment: @Slim Marten: please explain? If the above change is made it will always fire on any `.delete` element click.

Comment: sry dude, you are right. I had another error that messed it up. Now it works like a chamr. thanks for your support!

Comment: Do you also know a technique how to apply this for the document.ready() function? I need to reattach an .ajaxForm() function to a form which will also be updated

Comment: You cannot apply DOM ready the same way as that is not a bubbled event. You can either call your code after the Ajax success, or get the Ajax success to broadcast a custom even with trigger, that can be caught at a higher element (which then applies any addins).