# How to hide/show billing fields depending on the chosen payment method

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have three fields on the site (all required), which should not be hidden initially on the checkout page, but when choosing this input with value="type1" you should show the fields with id billing_address_2_field, billing_code_postfield(should be mandatory when selecting a field).
When choosing the second payment method, value="type2" we hide (default, do not deactivate) the first and second fields, showing billing_file_uload_field. When choosing an innovative payment method, all three fields are hidden and become optional.

I used JS but unfortunately my code does not work cortically.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function handlePaymentMethodChange() {
    var selectedPaymentMethod = $('input[name="transaction_type"]:checked').val();
    var $addressField = $('#billing_address_2_field');
    var $postcodeField = $('#billing_postcode_field');
    var $fileUploadField = $('#billing_file_uload_field');

    $addressField.hide();
    $postcodeField.hide();
    $fileUploadField.hide();

    $addressField.find('input').prop('required', false);
    $postcodeField.find('input').prop('required', false);
    $fileUploadField.find('input[type="file"]').prop('required', false);

    if (selectedPaymentMethod === 'type1') {
      $addressField.show();
      $postcodeField.show();
      $addressField.find('input').prop('required', true);
      $postcodeField.find('input').prop('required', true);
    } else if (selectedPaymentMethod === 'type2') {
      $fileUploadField.show();
      $fileUploadField.find('input[type="file"]').prop('required', true);
    }
  }

  handlePaymentMethodChange();
  $('input[name="transaction_type"]').change(handlePaymentMethodChange);
});
</script>
```

```html
<li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_special_payment">
    <input id="payment_method_special_payment" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="special_payment" checked="checked" data-order_button_text="">

    <label for="payment_method_special_payment">
        Оплата на р/р (ФОП та юр. особи)    </label>
            <div class="payment_box payment_method_special_payment" style="">
            <p>ТЕКСТ ЗАПОЛНИТЬ 1!!</p>
<style>#transaction_type_field label.radio { display:inline-block; margin:0 .8em 0 .4em}</style><p class="form-row transaction_type form-row-wide" id="transaction_type_field" data-priority=""><label for="transaction_type_type1" class="">Payment Information&nbsp;<span class="optional">(необов'язково)</span></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="type1" name="transaction_type" id="transaction_type_type1" checked="checked"><label for="transaction_type_type1" class="radio ">Ввести реквізити компанії</label><input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="type2" name="transaction_type" id="transaction_type_type2"><label for="transaction_type_type2" class="radio ">Завантажити виписку (можна скріншот)</label><input type="radio" class="input-radio " value="type3" name="transaction_type" id="transaction_type_type3"><label for="transaction_type_type3" class="radio ">Передзвоніть мені</label></span></p>        </div>
    </li>







<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
        <p class="form-row form-row-wide address-field elementor-repeater-item-50cc1a8 jwb-field-required jwb-field-wrapper jwb-field-text validate-required" id="billing_address_1_field" data-priority="50" style="display: block;"><label for="billing_address_1" class="">Адреса вулиці&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="обов'язкове">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_address_1" id="billing_address_1" placeholder="" value="Marienstraße 45" autocomplete="address-line1"></span></p><p class="form-row form-row-first elementor-repeater-item-168946f jwb-field-optional address-field jwb-field-wrapper jwb-field-text validate-required" id="billing_address_2_field" data-priority="60" style="display: block;"><label for="billing_address_2" class="">Повна назва компанії&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="обов'язкове">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_address_2" id="billing_address_2" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="address-line2"></span></p><p class="form-row form-row-last elementor-repeater-item-e70c37c jwb-field-required address-field jwb-field-wrapper jwb-field-text validate-required" id="billing_postcode_field" data-priority="70" style="display: block;"><label for="billing_postcode" class="">ІПН/ЄДРПОУ&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="обов'язкове">*</abbr></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_postcode" id="billing_postcode" placeholder="Наприклад: 43712216" value="48282" autocomplete="postal-code"></span></p>
<p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required" id="billing_file_uload_field" data-priority="80" data-fcf-field="billing_file_uload">
    <label for="billing_file_uload">
        Виберіть файл для завантаження                  <abbr class="required" title="Required Field">*</abbr>
            </label>
    <span class="fcf-file-items" data-api-url="https://main.parovozchips.com/wp-json/flexible-checkout-fields-pro/v1/file-upload?_wpnonce=1c0c8e927f" data-api-error-code="fcf_file_upload_error" data-api-error-message="An unknown error has occurred. Try again." data-field-name="billing_file_uload" data-fcf-field-loaded="1">
                    <span class="fcf-file-item" data-index="0">
                <span class="fcf-file-draggable">
                    <input type="file" class="fcf-file-draggable-input" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,application/pdf,image/heic">
                    <span class="fcf-file-draggable-content">
                        <span class="fcf-file-draggable-error" hidden=""></span>
                        <span class="fcf-file-draggable-placeholder" hidden="">
                            Select File or Drag &amp; Drop                      </span>
                        <span class="fcf-file-draggable-loading" hidden="">
                            Uploading...                        </span>
                        <span class="fcf-file-draggable-preview">
                            <a href="https://main.parovozchips.com/flexible-checkout-fields/b8e500c34dba5871740f67a477ef6200" target="_blank">238-5-add_photo-128-0-683x1024-1.jpg</a>                      </span>
                    </span>
                    <button type="button" class="button fcf-file-draggable-delete">
                        Delete                  </button>
                </span>
                <input type="hidden" name="billing_file_uload[]" value="b8e500c34dba5871740f67a477ef6200" class="fcf-file-draggable-value fcf-input-field">
            </span>
            </span>
</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Is it giving any error messages in your developer console?

Comment: absolutely no bugs, nothing changes on the site. the file with the code is cortical connected. I think it should be done through php

Comment: You're just toggling divs on the page, so that should be javascript, not PHP. If you used PHP, you'd need to reload the page or replace the div each time. I'd suggest adding logging with `console.log()` to see if anything triggers, and also try some of those lines manually in your Developer Console. At this point, you don't know if it's just not triggering or not hitting different sections. You don't show your HTML, so we can't see if the fields it should be triggering on and for are correct

Comment: i edit my post, you can check

Comment: From what I can tell, [it should work](https://jsfiddle.net/vfk9r1jg/2/).

Comment: This code I added to the hat of the site, when loading the site initially selected the first type and so the fields with the download of the file immediately hides. But with other options, nothing happens with the code. I believe that there is some sort of internal loading or AJAX loading of the payment form itself and therefore the code on the further does not work. you can check it now on the site - https://main.parovozchips.com/checkout

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yes, that payment section is loaded with ajax, so you have to "reattach" the jquery. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012618/how-do-i-reattach-an-event-to-a-new-loaded-dom-element-with-ajax might be of some help

Comment: Hi @RuslanGT, it would be a good idea if you check out the guide about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will help you to get answered quickly, save time to who's reading, and ideally help other users that will face the same problem in the future. As a general rule try to focus on the functionality instead of how you're using it. "How to show/hide html form fields depending on input" would have been a right title here, and probably leaded you to similar existing questions. Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery dynamic form display on select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536840/jquery-dynamic-form-display-on-select-option)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your code 100% and therefore cannot understand the logic of how form fields are enabled/disabled. So, here is a generalized example that you can apply to your own use case.

The main trick here, is that I use fieldsets that can be enabled/disabled based on the selection if the radio buttons. If a fiedset is disabled the form fields inside the fiedset will not be part of the submit request of the form. It is like disabling them all. If a fieldset i disabled I hide it using CSS.

An input (with a specific name) element can be present in more fieldsets -- that is not a problem.

The following example has two different "modes". The one that is in work now uses the object `fieldsets` to decide witch fiedsets are going to be enabled/displayed. The "mode" that I commented out will just enable one fieldset based on one radio button.

I hope that it is useful.

```js
const fieldsets = {
  t1: ['t1'],
  t2: ['t2'],
  t3: ['t1', 't3']
};

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (e.target.name == 'transactiontype') {
    let tid = e.target.value;
    let form = e.target.form;
    [...form.elements]
    .filter(elm => elm.type == 'fieldset')
      .forEach(elm => elm.disabled = true);
    // enable just one of the fiedsets
    //form[tid].disabled = false;
    // enable arbitraire fieldsets based on array
    fieldsets[tid].forEach(id => form[id].disabled = false);
  }
});

// if more input elements have the same name
// value should be copied the other elements
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.type == 'text') {
    let name = e.target.name;
    let form = e.target.form;
    if (form[name].length > 1) {
      [...form[name]].forEach(input => {
        if (input !== e.target) input.value = e.target.value;
      });
    }
  }
});

// just  for testing
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log([...data].join(';'));
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: none;
}

fieldset:disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label><input type="radio" name="transactiontype" value="t1" checked>Transaction type 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="transactiontype" value="t2">Transaction type 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="transactiontype" value="t3">Transaction type 3</label>
  <fieldset name="t1">
    <label>Option 1<input type="text" name="opt1" required></label>
    <label>Option 2<input type="text" name="opt2" required></label>
    <label>Option 3<input type="text" name="opt3" required></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="t2" disabled>
    <label>Option 1<input type="text" name="opt1" required></label>
    <label>Option 2<input type="text" name="opt2" required></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="t3" disabled>
    <label>Option 4<input type="text" name="opt4" required></label>
    <label>Option 5<input type="text" name="opt5" required></label>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, I'll try to integrate it into my site a little later. I apologize for not immediately sending a link to my site - https://main.parovozchips.com/

Comment: Thank you for your code but I can not on my site in woocommerce apply such palai. I do not have access to the payment form

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how this can be done through a simpler and more understandable example:

```js
for (let radio of document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio][name=fld_type]")) {
    radio.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.querySelector(".container").className = "container " + this.value;
    });
}
```

```css
.container div {
    display: none;
}

.container.first div.first {
    display: block;
}

.container.second div.second {
    display: block;
}

.container.third div.third {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container first">
    <div class="first">
        <label>1.1. <input type="text"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="first">
        <label>1.2. <input type="text"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="first">
        <label>1.3. <input type="text"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <label>2.1. <input type="text"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <label>2.2. <input type="text"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <label>2.3. <input type="text"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
        <label>3.1. <input type="text"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
        <label>3.2. <input type="text"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
        <label>3.3. <input type="text"></label>
    </div>
</div>

  <p>Please select your field type:</p>
  <input id="first" type="radio" name="fld_type" value="first" checked>
  <label for="first">first</label><br>
  <input id="second" type="radio" name="fld_type" value="second">
  <label for="second">second</label><br>
  <input id="third" type="radio" name="fld_type" value="third">
  <label for="third">third</label>
```

We have a single container, which has the `container` class and either `first`, `second` or `third` class and this class is being changed whenever you click on one of the radio buttons with its value. The inner elements have corresponding classes and the inactive classes are hidden by default, whereas the active class's elements are being shown.